# Check if each number from a list matches a range in a int4range[]

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, range, postgresql-9.2

I have a field: `ages pg_catalog.int4range[][][]`
Example value is `{"[0,6)","[8,10)"}` which means 2 ranges 0-6 and 8-10.
How to add correct condition to WHERE clause to check:

- 9 and 3 fit example value
- 9 and 9 do not fit (only one value per range should be)

Something like `WHERE ages <@ ARRAY[9,3]`, `WHERE ages <@ ARRAY[9,9]`

**Update**
The logic describes contract conditions for applying child age rules. I was thinking it is attractive to keep all data inside one field and avoid several stages of checking and compare - just to intersect values and ranges.
Number of ranges is usually variable, can be 1,2,3,4 etc. Values for check are counted and applied only to matching number of ranges - if 3 ages then only arrays with 3 ranges inside.

Comment: This is a bad data model. Have two columns to indicate the start and end points of each interval (and a third to indicate whether it's closed, open, half-open on the left, or half-open on the right).

Comment: @JackManey: that is not necessary in Postgres. `int4range` is a *native* range datatype which contains all that logic. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html Having an array of ranges seems a bit strange though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: logic describes contract conditions for applying child age rules. I was thinking it is attractive to keep all data inside one field and avoid several stages of checking and compare - just to intersect values and ranges. So is it possible to do?

Comment: A hint on formatting: to force a line break add two spaces before the line break in the markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Clarify problem

You question displays a 1-dimensional array. So use a proper column definition:

```
ages int4range[]
```

Not that it makes any difference other than being confusing. I quote the chapter [Declaration of Array Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION) from the manual:

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
>   dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
>   considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
>   dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
>   `CREATE TABLE` is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time behavior.

Also, the question itself is ambiguous. Ex.:

```
INSERT INTO tbl(ages) VALUES ('{"[0,6)","[5,9)","[8,10)"}')
```

Test with: `'{5,8,7}'::int[]`.

If applied in order, the check *fails*:
`5` fits 1st range `[0,6)`.
`8` fits 2nd range `[5,9)`.
`7` doesn't fit 3nd range `[8,10)`.

However, applied in the different order `5,7,8`, the check *succeeds*. You need to

1. Either guarantee non-overlapping intervals.
2. Or apply the checks in a defined order.
3. Clarify that the number of elements on either side always matches.

Finally, edit the explanation about what you are trying to do into the question. Don't hide important information in comments.

### Answer

As per comment, assuming 1., 2. and 3. from the catalog above.
This query tests all `ages` (`array of int4range`) from `tbl` whether they fit a supplied `age_list` (`int[]`):

```
WITH tbl(id, ages) AS (
   VALUES
     (1, '{"[0,2)","[4,6)","[8,10)"}'::int4range[])
    ,(2, '{"[2,4)","[6,8)","[9,10)"}')
   )                                    -- stand-in for table
SELECT id, bool_and(i <@ r) AS passes_test
FROM  (
   SELECT id
         ,unnest('{1,5,9}'::int[]) AS i -- supply age_list here
         ,unnest(ages)             AS r
   FROM tbl
   ) AS sub
GROUP  BY 1
```

Returns:

```
 id | passes_test
----+------------
  1 | t
  2 | f
```

#### Major points

- The CTE `tbl` is just a stand-in for your table. You can remove it if `tbl` actually exists.
- The two [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) functions unnest the two arrays side by side. I add `id` (any unique column) to identify rows.
- Check for each element whether it is contained in the range with the [`<@` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) and re-aggregate with [`bool_and`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html). Returns `TRUE` if and only if all checks are `TRUE`.

Comment: 1. and 3. are Ok! Also it is normal to sort values before passing to check routine.

Comment: @revoua: If we can build on all these assumptions (including sorted arrays), it gets rather simple. See my solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also turned to unnest but could not cover all points. Many thanks!